# why the sum of columns exceeds 12?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

in twitter bootstrap 3, the maximum number of columns in the grid is 12. i can't figure out why in the official docs theres this example which exceeds it to 18:
http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed

```
<!-- Stack the columns on mobile by making one full-width and the other half-width -->
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8">.col-xs-12 .col-md-8</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is because rows that total more than 12 will wrap, allowing for a different presentation on mobile. You use the `col-xs` class to specify what portion of the screen to use at mobile sizes, and if you exceed 12 additional rows are created, whether or not the markup exists for that.

You can see this by resizing your browser on the demo page. Look specifically at the mobile, tablet, desktops and responsive reset examples:

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-responsive-resets

http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-example-mixed-complete